# What has changed in libssl.0.9.8o-7ubuntu2 so that it now breaks my Aventail client, and what should I do?

Tags: 12.04

I cannot install my Aventail client in Kubuntu 12.04 because it does not like 12.04's version of libssl.0.9.8. Although Aventail will install without complaining when libssl.0.9.8o-7ubuntu1 is installed, it's a different story with libssl.0.9.8o-7ubuntu2, the version that 12.04 wants to install. With 0.9.8o-7ubuntu2, I get the following errors:

Code:

```
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77c7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7798000)
        libssl.so.0.9.7 => not found
        libcrypto.so.0.9.7 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb776b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb75c5000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77c8000)
```

What has changed between 0.9.8o-7ubuntu1 and 0.9.8o-7ubuntu2? Is there a way for me to instruct my package management systems not to include libssl.0.9.8 in its updater?

Answer (score 3):

I got it working - well I can use Aventail on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit but on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit it does not work at all - startcui or starct do not work (please test and escalate to Sonicwall if you want).

To solve your lib issue

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8 
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.7
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.0.9.7
```

Comment: Great...Worked for me with Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 3):

Aventail 10.52 was installed and working on 11.10 x64. After upgrading to Precise Pangolin 12.04 x64 (64-bit) I fixed Aventail using:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8 /usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.7
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do in this case except to tell Update Manager not to update `libssl`. open the Update Manager by clicking the power cog and selecting "Software up to Date" or "Updates Available".

[image]

The update Manager will open and you will be presented with an window looking similar to this:

[image]

Uncheck the checkboxes for any updates with the package named `libssl` in them. Click "Install Updates" and enter your password when prompted. Repeat the next time you update your computer, and so forth.